# Archer questions on topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

The case for allowing questions about Archer:

- Cyborgs
- Space travel (occasional)
- Weird fantasy (as in illogical and unrealistic) timeline
- Futuristic weapons and technology (in occasional episodes)
- Frequent references to science fiction and fantasy works, especially LotR, and occasionally comic books and even Star Wars
- It's awesome

The case against allowing questions about Archer:

- Not strictly a science fiction or fantasy show (the show is more of an action adventure spy-themed comedy cartoon)
- Science fiction and fantasy elements are relatively few and far between

So, are questions about Archer on topic or not?

Comment: I'm minded to close this as a dupe of; [Are works that aren't SF per se, but have occasional SFnal elements on-topic?](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/337/are-works-that-arent-sf-per-se-but-have-occasional-sfnal-elements-on-topic-e/344#344)

Comment: @Richard - There's certainly a case to be made for marking this as a duplicate, but how about you let it sit and wait for others to vote on whether or not to close it as such?

Comment: Fair enough. I'll let it stew for a while but be aware that after the community has had its say, we're almost certainly going to come back full circle.

Comment: @Richard - I have an answer already, so if it gets closed sooner or later, no harm will be done.

Comment: @Richard - We'll see how the [first question on the subject](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/94354/why-does-archer-hate-cyborgs) does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's basically a spoof of James Bond, and includes many of the same spy-fi elements. It's basically as on topic as Bond is.

Comment: Do we have an official (or at least community consensus) position on the "on-topicness" of Bond? Saying it's "basically as on topic as Bond is" doesn't help if we don't.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist See the link in the first comment on the question.